# how to compare two arrays that are in different classes?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I got two arrays that i need to compare it they have the same value.

I got one `Ticket` class, and a NumberGenerator class.

In the `Ticket` class, I got an array that contain my "lucky numbers" and the `NumberGenerator`contains the winning numbers.

`
public class sammenligning

{
    public void jon ()
    {
        if (Arrays.equals(TicketRegister.getticketReg(),LottoMachine.listOfWinningNumbers())) {
            System.out.println("We have a winner!");
        }
    }
}
`
i get an error at the getticketReg (dnw)
(ticketReg is the name of the array)

Answer (score 2):

You should use Arrays.sort to sort the arrays first, then comparing arrays is trivial with Arrays.equals.

Answer (score 1):

Another question you should ask yourself, is where to do that comparison? If you "expose" the lucky numbers from the ticket to the rest of the world (using a public method), you may **break encapsulation**.

To keep it private and self-contained in `Ticket`, maybe you should have a method on your ticket, that goes like:

```
public boolean isWinningTicket(NumberGenerator numberGenerator) {
    // assuming both arrays are sorted
    return Arrays.equal(this.luckyNumbers, numberGenerator.getWinningNumbers());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Arrays.equals(aTicket.getNumbers(), aNumberGenerator.getNumbers())) {
    System.out.println("We have a winner!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

comparing two arrays do not need to be in same class you can compare these using following method

boolean isEqual = `Arrays.equals`(array1(ticket class lucky numbers),array2(NumberGenerator winning numbers) );

Answer (score 0):

Ticket class:

```
public class Ticket {
 private Integer [] tickets=new Integer[]{80,35,41};

    public Integer[] getTickets() {
        return tickets;
    }

    public void setTickets(Integer[] tickets) {
        this.tickets = tickets;
    }

}
```

NumberGenerator:

```
public class NumberGenerator {
    private Integer [] numbers=new Integer[]{51,85,80,35,41};

    public Integer[] getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumbers(Integer[] numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

}
```

TestClass To comparing:

```
for(int i=0;i<t.getTickets().length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<numberGenerator.getNumbers().length;j++)
            {
                if(t.getTickets()[i].equals(numberGenerator.getNumbers()[j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("Winner Number is::::"+t.getTickets()[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

and if all the elements are same of two arrays then use this

```
boolean blnResult = Arrays.equals(t.getTickets(),numberGenerator.getNumbers());
```